# How to put RTMP stream into variable in node.js

Tags: node.js, webrtc, rtmp

I am creating a server that receives an RTMP stream and sends it to a WebRTC peer.
CAM -> RTMP -> RTMP Server -> RTMP stream To peer (node.js)
I don't know how to move RTMP into webrtc stream.

Here's how to load a cam image on webrtc from a local browser.

```
let localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(CONSTRAINTS);
this.video.srcObject = localStream;
localStream.getTracks().forEach(
    track => this.rtc.addTrack(track, localStream)
);
```

But how do I burn an rtmp stream to a peer on a node.js server?

I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days.